# Can not get url sometime when I have intent filter

Tags: java, android

My project is download manager . I want to get the url then download  it.I works correctly but sometimes dont show the url.
I think that maybe I have internet connection.
here in  my manifest I use the this:

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

this is for my activity that handle downloading.
and here is my activity in this way I get the intent.

```
  final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String action = intent.getAction();


        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            Log.e("mhs","true");
            try {
                uri2 = intent.getData();
                uri = uri2.toString();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("error",e.toString());
            }

        showUrlDialog1();

    }
```

can anyone help me that why it is like this?
for example when I tired it show every time but it just very rarely happen that show nothing.

Comment: Well what is the problem that you cannot get the url? By the way: i see no url in your code. Nor download code. And you did not tell from where you receive the intent. Pretty unclear all.

Comment: I get the intent as you can see the code above but sometimes it did not return anything